# How do I get a script to load before masonry?

Tags: javascript, masonry, imagesloaded

I'm quite new to javascript so bear with me if this is described quite horribly... I'm sure there's a simple solution if someone could take the time to check this code for me:

http://nang-nang.net/masonry/index.html

^My test site

I'm trying to use Masonry but unloaded images are causing elements to overlap. There is a solution provided (in the Masonry appendix page) called ImagesLoaded, which I tried, but I couldn't get it to work. Then I thought, ImagesLoaded might not be working because the image that is causing the problem is being generated by another javascript...

I'm using a script that pulls the latest image from your tumblr blog. It's my latest tumblr image that isn't loading before Masonry arranges my elements. So the element after the tumblr element always appears on top of it. (I can't set the height of that image because it always varies.)

I guess my question is; how to do I get the tumblr script to load my latest tumblr image before Masonry can arrange my elements?

Comment: If they're both external scripts place the first script to be loaded before the second one.

Comment: You can initialize masonry first, than wait for your tumblr image and call `msnry.layout();` after the script is completed.

Comment: @Lugia101101 it seems even when I place the masonry script right above the closing body tag, it still arranges the page before the image has a chance to load.

Comment: @vorrtex when you say 'call msnrt.layout(); after the script is completed.' I don't know what you mean by 'call'. How to write that... could you be very specific? Thanks very much

Comment: Like. `window.onload = function(){msnry.layout();};`?

Comment: I don't know how exactly, but there should be javascript code where you create this layout, and the script where you pull the latest image. So the mentioned script probably has some callback function which is executed when the image is loaded.

Comment: Thanks @Lugia101101 but seeing as I've never written javascript before I don't know how to write/implement these functions... I literally need someone to give me a code snippet to paste into my page I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks @vorrtex but seeing as I've never written javascript before I don't know how to write/implement these functions... I literally need someone to give me a code snippet to paste into my page I'm afraid.

Comment: I cannot help if you haven't tried to write code yourself. Remove the `data-masonry-options` attribute, replace it by your own javascript code like `new Masonry...`, then add the `imagesLoaded` function after `document.getElementById('ji-tumblr-photo--1').setAttribute('src', tumblr_api_read.posts[0]['photo-url-400']);`. When you write your code yourself and it still doesn't work - update your question and ask exactly what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it's me @Rishit Bansal again! I finally looked into your problem in detail and got the tested solution! There was a lot of new edits than the previous anser so i posted a new answer.... Ok anyway here is what you have to do-
1. Make a new js file and call it arrangemasonry.js  . Here is the code in arrangemasonry.js-

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

2.save the file in the same folder as index.html.
3.Here is the index.html edited correct code-

index.html-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Masonry</title>


<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(http://www.nang-nang.net/concrete3.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bebas_neueregular';
    src: url('http://www.nang-nang.net/tumblr/bebasneue-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://www.nang-nang.net/tumblr/bebasneue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://www.nang-nang.net/tumblr/bebasneue-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://www.nang-nang.net/tumblr/bebasneue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://www.nang-nang.net/tumblr/bebasneue-webfont.svg#bebas_neueregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
h1 {
    font-family: "bebas_neueregular", Arial Narrow, Arial;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #666666;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
h2 {
    font-family: "bebas_neueregular", Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #a80000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a:link {
    color: #a80000;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
    color: #a80000;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #a9a9a9;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #a80000;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.item {
    width: 300px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-image: url(http://www.nang-nang.net/portfolio/images/80bg.png);
    font-family: Lucida Grande, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">




    <!-- ///// ONE /////-->
    <div class="item">
        <h1>Nang-nang</h1>
        <font face="Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="5">
    ..................................................
    </font>
        <div style="font-size:14px;">nang-nang.net is the portfolio of digital designer Sam Roberts, who also goes by the online moniker <em>bubblejam</em>
        </div>
    </div>





    <!-- ///// TWO /////-->
    <div class="item">
        <a href="http://bubblejam.tumblr.com/tagged/places-I-have-worked" target="_blank">
            <h1>Worked for</h1>
        </a>
        <font face="Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="5">
    ..................................................
    </font>
        <span style="font-family:Lucida Grande, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">
    <a href="" target="_blank"  style="text-decoration:none;">Ted Baker</a> 
    <font color="#000000" size="-3">&bull;</font> 
    <a href="http://bubblejam.tumblr.com/tagged/ASOS" target="_blank"  style="text-decoration:none;">ASOS</a> 
    <font color="#000000" size="-3">&bull;</font> 
    <a href="http://bubblejam.tumblr.com/tagged/by-the-scruff" target="_blank"  style="text-decoration:none;">By The Scruff</a> 
    <font color="#000000" size="-3">&bull;</font> 
    <a href="http://bubblejam.tumblr.com/tagged/joythestore" target="_blank"  style="text-decoration:none;">JOY</a> 
    <font color="#000000" size="-3">&bull;</font> 
    <a href="http://bubblejam.tumblr.com/tagged/vice" target="_blank"  style="text-decoration:none;">Vice</a> 
    <font color="#000000" size="-3">&bull;</font> 
    <a href="http://bubblejam.tumblr.com/tagged/tv-print-factory" target="_blank"  style="text-decoration:none;">TV Print Factory</a> 
    <font color="#000000" size="-3">&bull;</font> 
    <a href="http://bubblejam.tumblr.com/tagged/buballs" target="_blank"  style="text-decoration:none;">Buballs</a> 
    <font color="#000000" size="-3">&bull;</font> 
    <a href="http://bubblejam.tumblr.com/tagged/don%27t-panic" target="_blank">
    Don't Panic</a> <font color="#000000" size="-3">&bull;</font> 
    <a href="http://bubblejam.tumblr.com/tagged/twentysix-london" target="_blank">  
    Twentysix Digital</a>
    </span>
    </div>



    <!-- ///// THREE /////-->
    <div class="item">
        <h2>Nang-nang photoblog</h2>

        <!--start of tumblr script
        taken from http://jiapps.com/free-stuff/tumblr-widget-for-your-website.html 
    -->

        <div class='ji-tumblr-photos' style="max-width:280px; overflow:hidden; border:solid 10px white; text-align:center;">
            <a id='ji-tumblr-url--1' href=''>
                <img border='0' style='margin-left:-25%;' id='ji-tumblr-photo--1' src='' alt='' />
            </a>

        </div>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://bubblejam.tumblr.com/api/read/json?number=1&type=photo'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.getElementById('ji-tumblr-photo--1').setAttribute('src', tumblr_api_read.posts[0]['photo-url-400']);
        document.getElementById('ji-tumblr-url--1').setAttribute('href', 'http://bubblejam.tumblr.com');
        </script>
        <!-- end of tumblr script-->

        <br />A collection of illustration, art, GIFs, cartoons, music, fashion, videos &amp; all round design that I find candid or inspirational. <em>Since Aug 2012.</em>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="http://bubblejam.tumblr.com" target="_blank" title="bubblejam on Tumblr">bubblejam on tumblr >></a>
    </div>





    <!-- ///// FOUR /////-->
    <div class="item">
        <h2>Instagram</h2>
        <!-- SnapWidget -->
        <iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/in/?u=bmFuZ25hbmduZXR8aW58MjgwfDF8MXx8bm98MHxub25lfG9uU3RhcnR8bm8=&v=19414" title="Instagram Widget" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:solid 10px white; overflow:hidden; width:280px; height:280px"></iframe>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="http://instagram.com/nangnangnet" target="_blank" title="nangnangnet on Instagram">nangnangnet on Instagram >></a>
    </div>





    <!-- ///// FIVE /////-->
    <div class="item">
        <iframe width="300" height="300" src="tweets2.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="http://twitter.com/bubblejam" target="_blank" title="bubblejam on twitter">bubblejam on twitter >></a>
    </div>





</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "arrangemasonry.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>




<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

3.This should work as i have tested it.Wait patiently for the page to load as the images will get arranged only after the images have full loaded.Tell me if you have any further problems.

Comment: it works! I understand now... by saving the script externally (that was the part I missed out previously) and then calling it at the end of my code it will load the masonry last. I googled 'downloadJSAtOnload' and now realise this is how you defer a script till last. This is totally perfect for me. Thank you so much!!

Comment: You can mark the answer correct as it will also help other people with the same problem to find the correct answer.@bubblejam

Comment: Oops right almost forgot that. If you'd like any coding credit on my site (when it's complete) please let me know! @Rishit Bansal

Comment: No, its fine. I don't need any coding credit as most of my code was from the internet itself. Anyway, thanks for asking, and good luck with your website. @bubblejam

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work out for you-
Keep the tumblr code in the index.html file itself between some script tags. Now you can write some javascript like this so that the external masonry file is loaded only after the index page has loaded-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "masonry.pkgd.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

I hope this solved your problem! If you didnt understand a part of my answer i am free to more edits, just comment....
PS:Be sure to remove any script tags you added before to masonry.pkgd.min.js

Comment: Hi @Rishit Bansal I put this script at the bottom of the page, just above the </body> tag and uploaded this to http://nang-nang.net/masonry/index2.html

It doesn't seem to have worked unfortunately. Did I do everything correctly?

Comment: I am VERY SORRY for late respose as i had to do an urgent errand. I checked out your page. I think you have forgotten to remove the <script src="masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script> in line 10 of your index2.html page. I told you to do so in the "PS:" i mentioned in my answer. Not removing the script tag makes the masonry script load at the starting itself. Ok so try it out again and tell me it if works...(I hope it does!) and again i am sorry for the late response! @bubblejam

Comment: that is perfectly fine! You are the one helping me, please take all the time you need. Ok - after your last feed back I removed the <script src="masonry... etc> from the head. Even with your code at the bottom I found this stopped the masonry working all together. 

I made sure my js file was uploaded to my root folder, so 'element.src = "masonry.pkgd.min.js";' should be directing correctly to my hosted js file... so I'm unsure what is wrong now sorry! :(

Comment: Check out my new answer @bubblejam